# Tooltipster jQuery plugin to use for checking empty textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tooltip

I am using tooltipser to put style on my website, but I tried this code to check if the textbox is empty but it did not work. can anyone help me?

### HTML FORM

```
<form name="studentform" method="POST" action="index.php" role="form" onsubmit="return check(this)" autocomplete="off">
    <center>
        <input type="text" name="suid" class="suid" id="suid" placeholder="STUDENT NO." title="Student No. is required">
        <input type="password" name="pass"  id="pass" class="pass" placeholder="PASSWORD" title="Password is required">
        <input type="submit" name="login" class="sub" value="LOG IN">
    </center>
</form>
```

### jQUERY (Tooltipster)

```
    <script>
        function check()
        {
            if (!studentform.suid.value)
            {

                $('.suid').tooltipster({
                animation: 'grow',
                delay: 200,
                theme: 'tooltipster-default',
                touchDevices: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                position: 'right'
                });return (false);

            }
            if (!studentform.pass.value)
            {
                $('.pass').tooltipster({
                animation: 'grow',
                delay: 200,
                theme: 'tooltipster-default',
                touchDevices: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                position: 'right'
                });
                return (false);
            }
            else {return true;}
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return(false);`, it's causing the function to end after successfully initializing tooltipster in the first if: https://jsfiddle.net/LyaevuLn/2/

Comment: Sorry but you misunderstood me, The checking was doing fine, I checked it using javascript alert boxes. I want to figure out how to make the tooltip appear

Comment: I got it, working code here: https://jsfiddle.net/LyaevuLn/2/ updated the answer as well, return(false); was causing the function to stop executing once it successfully initialized tooltipster in the first if condition.